# Python function that only rounds down?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Outside of coding my own, is there any built in Python function that only rounds integers down? I'm looking for something with a similar function to the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function, but would, say, evaluate

```
myFunction(3900, -3)
```

as `3000`, not `4000`.

And, if there is no built in function fitting that description, do you have any advice for coding my own?

Comment: What does the "-3" mean?

Comment: In the `round` function, it rounds to that many digits after the decimal point.

Comment: It provides the place value to which the round() function will round. Positive integers go past the decimal point, while negative integers go before it. In this case, -3 means to round to the nearest thousand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple trick: substract half a decade/hundred/thousand/etc. based on the required precision and use the `round()` builtin.

This would give you something like this:

```
>>> round_down = lambda x, prec: round(x - 5 * (10 ** (prec - 1)) + 1, -prec)
>>> round_down(2900, 3)
2000
>>> round_down(290, 2)
200
```

Notice that when substracting, you have to add 1 to the number to be passed to `round`, because otherwise in the extreme case where you called

```
round_down(3000, 3)
```

you would actually be calling

```
round(2500, -3)
```

which would evaluate to `2000`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a trick to subtract *before* using `round` such that it always will round down and avoid having to use `lambda`.

```
def fun(num,spots):
     return (int(round(num - 0.5*10**(-spots), spots) ))
```

**Outputs:**

```
>>>fun(3900, -3)
3000
>>>fun(32948, -2)
32900
>>>fun(3001, -3)
3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def foo(a,b):

    return (math.floor(a/(10**b)))*(10**b)
```